# 'Pre render' Screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, optimization, render

So basically: I've got a List with some jobs, this is my `JobsView`. When someone click on a Job I navigate them to the Job view where display the job's location with react-native-maps andthe job's details.
But rendering react-native-maps every single time can take quite the time. (1s)
So:

1. On the `JobsScreen` I click on a Job
2. I fire the navigate func
3. `JobScreen` renders the maps and details. THIS is a problem as this takes 1 sec every single time, so somehow I want to pre render the map but got no idea how. :/. (or is there a better way for doing this type of thing?)

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, I think, navigation will cause your map view disposed each time you touch `back` button.

So my suggestion is using CSS. You create the map component but hide it with CSS styling.

When user clicks on list item, instead of navigation, we show map component (by CSS styling again).

Because we don't use navigation => so you can:
 + case 1: customize back button touch behavior to hide the map, or
 + case 2: build a close button for map.

That's the idea. Hope it helps.